# rxjs ReplaySubject handle

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, subject

i have a problem with a template i am using in angular 4.
This template implement a notification system, where you can add new notifications, but the documentation do not specify how one can delete the elements of the observer ReplaySubject.

The template implement this as a service as follows:

```js
private notificationsList: Notification[] = [];
  // a stream that publishes new notifications only once
  public newNotifications: Subject<Notification> = new Subject<Notification>();

  // `notifications` is a stream that emits an array of the most up to date notifications
  public notifications: ReplaySubject<Notification[]> =
      new ReplaySubject<Notification[]>(1);

  // `updates` receives _operations_ to be applied to our `notifications`
  // it's a way we can perform changes on *all* notifications (that are currently
  // stored in `notifications`)
  public updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  // action streams
  public create: Subject<Notification> = new Subject<Notification>();
  // public markThreadAsRead: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    // recois des operation, et les fais sur la liste interne, puis diffuse le
    // resultat sur notifications
    this.updates.subscribe((ope) => {
      this.notificationsList = ope(this.notificationsList);
      console.log(this.notificationsList);
      this.notifications.next(this.notificationsList);
    });

    this.newNotifications
      .map(function(notification: Notification): INotificationsOperation {
        return (notifications: Notification[]) => {
          return notifications.concat(notification);
        };
      })
      .subscribe(this.updates);

  }

  // an imperative function call to this action stream
  public addNotification(notification: Notification): void {
    this.newNotifications.next(notification);
  }
```

I try to ask to the owner how i can delete an actual element of the notification list, but he just tell me that i can access the "notifications" subject to receive the last version of it. But do not mention how i can actually delete an element of the list.

Some one know something about?

Thanks!

Comment: ReplaySubject holds your last emitted value's, in your case the last one since you construct the object with (1), so you can't delete a notification from the ReplaySubject itself, but you can get the value from it, and if you have like ID or something of the notification, you can just delete it manually from the array, and emit the new value to the ReplaySubject.

Comment: If you want to ignore the stored element, you can just use skip function : `replaySubject$.skip(1).subscribe()`

Comment: So if you would like to delete one element of the "notificationsList", for example the first one notificationsList[0], how you would implement a function to do this?

Comment: So your problem is "how to delete an element from a list"?
In this case : 
If you want to keep the list size unchanged: `del notificationList[0]`
If you want to delete the element and rescale the list : `notificationList.splice(0,1) // delete 1 element starting from 0th position and resize`

Comment: Yes, i actually try to delete one element of the list, but the code i publish before is a servise of an template in angular, and the notificationList is private, so i need to do this from the public property newNotifications, notifications, updates or create. I really dont know how rxjs subject, replay subject works, and cannot figure out how can i do it. For now I do something that is not that nice, I create a new list outside and use "this.notifServ.notifications.next(newNotif);" to update the list, it works, but not that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a public function that you can use. 
I added a comment to let you see which part of the code you can modify if you want to delete elements by name for example, or don't want to resize the list. 
Explanation at the end of my post.

```
  private notificationsList: Notification[] = [];
  // a stream that publishes new notifications only once
  public newNotifications: Subject<Notification> = new Subject<Notification>();
  public removeNotificationByIndex$ : Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
  // `notifications` is a stream that emits an array of the most up to date notifications
  public notifications: ReplaySubject<Notification[]> =
      new ReplaySubject<Notification[]>(1);

  // `updates` receives _operations_ to be applied to our `notifications`
  // it's a way we can perform changes on *all* notifications (that are currently
  // stored in `notifications`)
  public updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  // action streams
  public create: Subject<Notification> = new Subject<Notification>();
  // public markThreadAsRead: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    // recois des operation, et les fais sur la liste interne, puis diffuse le
    // resultat sur notifications
    this.updates.subscribe((ope) => {
      this.notificationsList = ope(this.notificationsList);
      console.log(this.notificationsList);
      this.notifications.next(this.notificationsList);
    });

    this.newNotifications
      .map(function(notification: Notification): INotificationsOperation {
        return (notifications: Notification[]) => {
          return notifications.concat(notification);
        };
      })
      .subscribe(this.updates);

    this.removeNotificationByIndex$
     .map(function(index: number){
        return (notifications: Notification[]) => {
        // >>>> DELETE METHOD IS TO BE DEFINED DOWN HERE !
        notifications.splice(index,1);
        // >>>> DELETE METHOD IS TO BE DEFINED UP HERE !
      return notifications
     };
     })
     .subscribe(this.updates);

  }

  // an imperative function call to this action stream
  public addNotification(notification: Notification): void {
    this.newNotifications.next(notification);
  }

  // delete the element in the "index" position of the list. 
  // /!\ Resizes the list 
  public removeNotificationsByIndex(index: number): void {
    this.removeNotificationByIndex$.next(index);
  }
```

**What are the changes ?**

```
public removeNotificationByIndex$ : Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
```

This subject will receive (asynchronously) an index, and trigger a process using this index.

```
 this.removeNotificationByIndex$
 .map(function(index: number){
    return (notifications: Notification[]) => {
    // >>>> DELETE METHOD IS TO BE DEFINED DOWN HERE !
    notifications.splice(index,1);
    // >>>> DELETE METHOD IS TO BE DEFINED UP HERE !
  return notifications
 };
 })
 .subscribe(this.updates);
```

When the index is emitted (i.e you use the associated imperative function), a function (ES6 arrow function) is generated from it. This is it :

```
(notifications: Notification[]) => {
    // >>>> DELETE METHOD IS TO BE DEFINED DOWN HERE !
    notifications.splice(index,1);
    // >>>> DELETE METHOD IS TO BE DEFINED UP HERE !
  return notifications
 };
```

This function is passed to `this.update`, which will apply it. In this context, `ope` is this function. when received, `this.notificationList` is modified as follow :

```
this.notificationsList = ope(this.notificationsList);
```

Finally, this new list is published to the ReplaySubject `notifications`:

```
this.notifications.next(this.notificationsList);
```

Which propagate this new list to all its subscribers.

Voilà :). Good luck !

Comment: Glad if it helped !